# The use of -ize and -ise in the UK?

Tags: orthography, ise-ize

I got a translation assignment where I am to use UK English but with -ize spelling.

*The European Union switched from -ize to -ise some years ago in its English language publications, meaning that -ize spellings are found in older legislative acts and -ise spellings in more recent ones*.

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#-ise.2C_-ize_.28-isation.2C_-ization.29

The wikipedia link is interesting.

Apparently -ize used in British English is used in Oxford publications (which refuse -ise) even though -ise seems to be preferred in Australia and New Zealand and UK itself (3:2 ratio).

What are your thoughts on this. Is using UK English with -ize spelling the right or wrong way to approach it?

And is -ize prevalent in US English?

P.S.: I'm not a native speaker, these things are not obvious to me.

Comment: +1 Good points. The scope seems too broad, I'm afraid the question is not to the point.

Comment: Thank you. How could I ask this question without being subject to an heated debate? I sincerely want to know. Perhaps I could try again asking the question again if that is alright.

Comment: We need to be specific -- one point to be answered in one post. '*Is -ize prevalent in US English?*' -- OK. '*What are your thoughts on this?*' -- Not OK on ELU. '*Is using UK English with -ize spelling the **right or wrong way** to approach it?*' -- Not OK on ELU. (I think so.)