# Is the use of ‘ize’ ever standard for any word over the use of ‘ise’ in UK English?

Tags: british-english, orthography

Is there any occasion upon which in British English, the ‘z’ is normally used and the ending ‘ise’ would be incorrect?

Comment: Hello, james. (1) 'British English' is a misnomer here (at least), as both the -ize and the -ise spelling choices are common in the UK. (The former is used by perhaps 40% of Brits.) See [The use of -ize and -ise in the UK](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/84102/the-use-of-ize-and-ise-in-the-uk). (2) The request for lists is not on-topic on ELU, though [s vs z in ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80599/s-vs-z-in-be-vs-ae) has two useful ones. (3) the verb 'prize' is still normally distinct from 'prise' amongst Brits:

Comment: 'Some words take only the -z- form worldwide, for example _capsize, seize_ (except in the legal phrases _to be seised of_ or _to stand seised to_), _size_ and _prize_ (only in the sense of winning, not as forcing open with a lever). These, however, do not contain the suffix -ize.' [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#Exceptions_3)]

Comment: Yes Prize is a good example of 'ize' being standard in my experience. Standardisation by algorithm (spell checkers) is causing me to question if i should rather have written 'Standardization'

Comment: I thought the preferred American spelling of the verb meaning to *pry* (off a lid) was *prise* (and to *prize* was to *value/cherish*),  but m-w says I'm wrong.

Comment: If your spell-checker is set to US conventions, it will probably reject/'correct' -ise, -ising, -isation etc spelling variants throughout. Even with UK conventions, the -ise etc spellings are far from universal. I always add the -ise variant to the 'dictionary' when it's flagged, as I choose this practice. It's almost universal in 'BrE' crosswords.

Comment: This is based upon a misconception.  When I was doing English O Level I was always taught that -ize is the British norm and -ise is only used in the USA.  Any homework submitted with -ise would be marked down.  Since then, the lines have blurred to make the distinction irrelevant.

Comment: @Chenmunka Your teachers were apparently the ones with the misconception. [Google 1-grams for realise/realize in their 'British English' corpus, 1800-2019](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=realise%2Crealize&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crealise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crealize%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Crealise%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Crealize%3B%2Cc0). O-Levels 1951 - 1997.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth:  Maybe so.  But the question is still likely to fall into the realms of center/centre and color/colour arguments where common usage has changed over time.

Comment: Boswell's Life of Johnson, the novels of Smollett, Sterne, etc, are full of -ize endings  - surprized, realized, patronized, etc. Even surprize (verb).

Comment: I have a [detailed answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153392/is-vapourise-considered-incorrect-even-in-british-english/335264#335264) in response to one such question on vaporize/vaporise. In brief, this documents the fact that in the early 20th century "ize" not "ise" was the standard form in British English (but, I would add "yse" not "ize"), and how "ise" became common. The topic has also been discussed numerous times, as a search of the site will show. I am therefore voting to close.

Comment: This should answer your question: [Is "vapourise" considered incorrect, even in British English?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153392/is-vapourise-considered-incorrect-even-in-british-english)

Answer (score 1):

Is there any occasion upon which in British English, the ‘z’ is normally used and the ending ‘ise’ would be incorrect?

The OED uses the -ize form as the primary word in its relevant entries. Although not "official" the OED is recognized/recognised as a dictionary "of record" - with that authority -ise and -ize are correct.

Comment: A [2011 corpus study by Shin'ichiro Ishikawa, Professor of Applied Linguistics at the School of Languages & Communication, Kobe University](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/305618893_Duality_in_the_Spelling_of_English_Verb_Suffixes_-ize_and_-ise_A_Corpus-based_Study) concluded: 'Our corpus-based studies have revealed that (1) –ize is used exclusively in American English, while both –ize and –ise are used in British English; (2) ... while –ize had been used more in the past, ... now –ise is becoming standard in British English ....' What corpora does OED use? OP asks about 'BrE'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *What corpora does OED use?* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_English_Corpus. Please include the research you’ve done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. :)

Comment: Thank you. To quote, 'It includes language from the UK, the United States, Ireland, Australia, New Zealand, the Caribbean, Canada, India, Singapore, and South Africa. The text is mainly collected from web pages; some printed texts, such as academic journals, have been collected to supplement particular subject areas. The sources are writings of all sorts, from "literary novels and specialist journals to everyday newspapers and magazines and from Hansard to the language of blogs, emails, and social media".' So not 'BrE' specific at all, especially if done on a pro-rata basis.

Comment: The entries for suffixes "-ise" and "-ize" are as follows: 1. **-ise, suffix1** *(see -ize suffix)*. -- *A frequent spelling of -ize suffix*, suffix forming verbs, which see. 2. **-ize** **Forms:  -ise, -ize.** -- **Etymology:** Cognate with French -ise-r, Italian -izare, Spanish -izar, < late Latin -izāre, -īzāre... The entries clearly imply that "-ize" is the suffix of choice (it being the fuller entry), but that there is always an option...

Comment: But 50% more Brits seem to choose 'not the suffix of choice', so is OED being prescriptive or telling everyone to follow trends in say Indian English?

Comment: It is trusting to the good sense of the English speaking public...

Comment: So you're ducking the issue that OED doesn't merely address UK usage, and is out of sync with this here.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood - I probably was not clear enough. The OED puts the "-ize" version first. I suspect that the original lexicographer disagreed (quite rightly) with the 19th century "-ise" idea, rather than consciously choosing Noah Webster's spelling or being dictated to by numbers in a corpus - we see this in the entry "**colour | color**, n.1" where the BE spelling is first. To the researcher, this should provide a clue...

Comment: Saying that -ize forms are superior to -ise forms in British usage is falling foul of the etymological fallacy.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth you have extended your argument to words that are not there and meanings that do not exist. Try to find the word "superior" in anything the OED says on the matter - it is a preference. Preference does not indicate superiority.

Comment: 'The entries clearly imply that '-ize' is the suffix of choice'. An estimated 60% (or above, Ishikawa's 2011 findings) of people using 'BrE' in written etc form, one assumes also having 'good sense', select '-ise' as the 'suffix of choice'.